# password_verify doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to make a login-register website for learning purposes and I can't make the **password_verify** work. The registration works perfectly. The value from the fetched array in the login.php is the same as in the database. The database connection works. Still, it always goes to Access denied when calling the password_verify function.

***index.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!--  Head -->

<head>

    <title>Small Content Management System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<!-- End head -->




<!-- Body -->

<body>

    <div id="login">
        <h2>Small CMS</h2>
        <form name="login" method="post" action="functions/login.php">
            Username:</br>
            <input type="text" name="username"></br>
            Password:</br>
            <input type="password" name="password"></br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <span id="register"><a href="register.php">Don't have an account? Register!</a></span>
    </div>

</body>

<!-- End Body -->

</html>
```

***register.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!--  Head -->

<head>

    <title>Small Content Management System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/register.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<!-- End head -->




<!-- Body -->

<body>

    <div id="login">
        <h2>Small CMS</h2>
        <form name="register" method="post" action="functions/register.php">
            Username:</br>
            <input type="text" name="username"></br>
            E-mail:</br>
            <input type="text" name="email"></br>
            Password:</br>
            <input type="password" name="password"></br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
        <span id="register"><a href="index.php">Already have an account? Login!</a></span>
    </div>

</body>

<!-- End Body -->

</html>
```

***login.php***

```
<?php

include_once '../../db.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (trim($username) != '' && trim($password) != '') {
        $con = new Connection();
        $query = $con->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
        $query->bindParam(1, trim($username)) ;
        $query->execute();

        $res = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (password_verify(trim($password), trim($res['password']))) {
            echo 'Access granted!';
        } else {
            echo 'Access denied!';
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Username or password invalid!';
    }
}
```

***functions/register.php***

```
<?php

include_once('../../db.php');


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // Error message to catch
    $err = '';

    // Check if user, password and email are empty
    if (trim($username) === '') {
        $err = 'Invalid username!</br>';
    }

    if (trim($password) === '') {
        $err .= 'Invalid password!</br>';
    }

    if (trim($email) === '') {
        $err .= 'Invalid email!<br>';
    }


    // Checking if user is already in use
    $con = new Connection();
    $query = $con->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?');
    $query->bindParam(1, $username);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->rowCount();
    if ($results != 0) {
        $err .= 'Username already in use!</br>';
    }

    // Checking if email is already in use
    $con = new Connection();
    $query = $con->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?');
    $query->bindParam(1, $email);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->rowCount();
    if ($results != 0) {
        $err .= 'Email already in use!</br>';
    }

    // Inserting new user into database
    if ($err === '') {

        // Connecting to db
        $con = new Connection();
        $query = $con->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $options = [
            'cost' => 12,
        ];
        $new_pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
        $query->bindParam(1, trim($username));
        $query->bindParam(2, trim($new_pass));
        $query->bindParam(3, trim($email));
        $query->execute();

    } else {
        echo $err;
    }
}
```

Comment: firstly, is the column length long enough to accomodate the hash? if it's too short and is stored as such, then retrieval will be impossible. Many use too low a number for their varchar. Use 255 which will also accomodate for the future. If that is the case, you need to start over with a new register/insert.

Comment: Column length might be the reason. Also from what I see, it looks like you are also trimming the password string before passing it to the password_verify function, but when creating the hash itself, you do not trim the string, so you might end up with different hash values?

Comment: @georaldc trimming is at times ok, should a user accidently hit the space bar at the end, or beginning of an input

Comment: @Fred-ii- makes sense, but the OP doesn't trim white space off the inputted password and instead, applies trim to the hash itself it seems before it gets stored

Comment: @georaldc even still. The hash shouldn't contain a space at the end, so it shouldn't affect it. I'm betting on column length and possibly the type. Some use types other than varchar; seen that happen a few times and being a *combination of*.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also add `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. also try removing the `trim()` function from `$query->bindParam(1, trim($username)) ;` and from `if (password_verify(trim($password), trim($res['password']))) {`

Comment: `@` me if you need me or I've hit a nerve or something. 20+ minutes into this and still no word from the OP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What I mean is if I store " foobar " as a password with the OP's code, wouldn't it create a hash using " foobar " as is (due to it not trimming the string before hash creation)? Then when we come to login.php, typing in "foobar" or " foobar " or "     foobar   " would never give a match because of the trim function always being applied (so it would always try to match "foobar" to " foobar ")

Comment: @georaldc You're right yes. No word from the OP, so you and I are basically trying to *guess, and guess where the crystal ball is* ;-)

Comment: Alright, it was the column length, thank you for your help!

Comment: I should make my comments an answer ;-) and you're welcome. seeing my first comment on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Alright, it was the column length, thank you for your help! –  Trooper*

Comment to answer.

Looking at your posted code, everything seems to check out.

*The likelyhood in my view at the time being:*

The column length should be long enough to accomodate the hash. If it's too short and is stored as such, then retrieval will be impossible. Many use too low a number for their varchar. Use 255 which will also accomodate for the future.

If that is the case, you need to start over with a new register/insert.

- Which in the end, was the case; too short a length for the column.